# Make component listen to updated data in a service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to create a service to pass data from a grand parent to its grand children and I want to call a method when the data has a specific value. I found a couple of interesting resources but I am missing some points.

Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';    

@Injectable()
export class PromptService {
  private messageSource: Subject<any>;
  messageSource$: Observable<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.messageSource = new Subject();
    this.messageSource$ = this.messageSource.asObservable();
  }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }
}
```

Here is an extract of the component that changes the value of the messageSource

```
@Component({
  selector: 'button',
  templateUrl: './button.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.scss'],
  providers: [PromptService]
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() module: ButtonModule;
  message: string;

  constructor(private promptService: PromptService) {
  }

  onClick(event, redirectLink?: string) {
    if (promptList) {
      …
    } else if (this.module.action === 'Cancel') {
      this.promptService.changeMessage("Hello from Sibling")
    } else {
      …
    }
  }
}
```

And finally an extract of the component in which I want to trigger `closePopup()` method when the observable value changes:

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, OnDestroy, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { PromptService } from './prompt.service';
import { forEach } from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'prompt',
  templateUrl: './prompt.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prompt.scss'],
  providers: [PromptService]
})
export class PromptComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  message$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private promptService: PromptService) {
    promptService.messageSource$.subscribe((message) => { this.message$ = message; });
  }

  closePopup() {
    const modalFirstChild = this.modalElement.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    this.modalElement.removeChild(modalFirstChild);
    this.removeBackground()
  }

  removeBackground() {
    if (!this.modalElement.getElementsByClassName('prompt_container').length) {
      this.modalElement.parentNode.removeChild(this.modalElement);
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

-- Update

Here is the button.html

```
<button (click)="onClick($event, module.link)">
  {{module.text}}
</button>
```

Comment: `promptService.messageSource$.subscribe((message) => { this.message$ = message; }); }` is erroneous.

Comment: i think you are looking on how to communicate between components look at this [question2](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)

Comment: You haven't called your close popup method. You need to add a call in the subscription based on your requirement value/logic.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, @SumitAgarwal, @RahulSingh, the issue seems to be that the `parent component` cannot subscribe to the `service`, since I can subscribe from the `child component`, and the `service` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish. According to your question though, you want to 'trigger closePopup() method when the observable value changes'. If that is the case, you should change your constructor of your `PromptComponent` to the following:

```
constructor(private promptService: PromptService) {
    promptService.messageSource$.subscribe((message) => { 
        this.message$ = message;
        this.closePopup();
    });
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do,the value of messageSource$ does not seem to be changed by the button component though. At least nothing happens in the subscribe inside `PromptComponent`

Comment: Would you share your `button.html` and `prompt.html` code?

Comment: I added the `button.html`, the `prompt.html` is more sensitive.

Comment: the problem does not seem to be coming from the subscribing method, because I can listen to the service property from either the service or the button. The parent component, aka the prompt cannot  listen.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, it turns out I was following [Angular cookbook](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) for parent-child communication through a service, but my architecture makes `buttonComponent` and `promptComponent` siblings.

While I was working I did set my `promptService` as a provider in each component and they were unrelated. Providing the `PromptService` in the `AppModule` fixed the problem!